# How to check iPad Compatibility in Safari browser (without iPad)?

Tags: ios

I need to know my web application is work in iPad, but I don't have iPad with me, so someone told that, we can check this compatibility in Safari browser, but how?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit system installed latest version of Safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use iOS simulator which is built into xcode.

Xcode may already be installed on a OSX system or you can either download from [appstore](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) or [apple Dev site](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can go to http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html for more information about this tool.

Set the user agent to iPad Safari. This should work.

Note, this is only a representation...